# excel formula to return value based on multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking for a formula that can search a table like the below and return on a different sheet a currency rate if i input the date. For example in a different excel i will put 2015.03.08 and i want to return me the USD and RUM value as of that date. Thank you!

```
            USD      GBP     RUB      PLN     TRY
2015.02.28  1.1191  0.7249  68.4454 4.1404  2.8002
2015.03.08  1.0838  0.7204  65.4411 4.1261  2.8374
2015.03.15  1.0539  0.7128  65.6039 4.1375  2.7672
2015.03.19  1.0588  0.721   64.4052 4.1382  2.7635
2015.03.23  1.0817  0.7235  64.1198 4.1202  2.7787
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [VLOOKUP with multiple criteria](http://superuser.com/questions/685818/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria)

Comment: To me this sounds like you want to return multiple values with one lookup, is that correct? In which case this is not a duplicate question as the name does suggest.

Comment: Do you expect to get an exact match for the lookup date - for example would you want to look up 2015.03.11? (and presumably get the values for the previous date in the table)

Answer (score 0):

If you're currency rates are in a "table" .. like this:

```
  Date         USD       GBP      RUB      PLN      TRY
  2015.02.28  1.1191   0.7249   68.4454  4.1404   2.8002 
  2015.03.08  1.0838   0.7204   65.4411  4.1261   2.8374 
  2015.03.15  1.0539   0.7128   65.6039  4.1375   2.7672 
  2015.03.19  1.0588   0.721    64.4052  4.1382   2.7635 
  2015.03.23  1.0817   0.7235   64.1198  4.1202   2.7787
```

Then you can do a "double" lookup by:

1) searching for the column your Currency code is in.

2) searching for the row your date is in.

3) use OFFSET (or INDEX) to pick the value you want.

`=OFFSET($A$1,MATCH("2015.03.15",A:A,0)-1,MATCH("RUB",1:1,0)-1,1,1)`