# Query two fields and select answer from third field (If or vlookup?)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to compare two fields in my data to a table and get the resulting fx value from table.

How the formula would read I would guess:

```
IF local_in_data = local_in_table AND 
  expense_in_data = expense_in_table THEN 
    take fx from table to data
```

data is:

```
expense  local  fx(formula)
EUR      USD    (formula) sh = 1.2
USD      USD    (formula) sh = 1.0
```

table is:

```
local   expense  fx
USD     EUR      1.2
USD     USD      1.0
EUR     USD      .08
USD     JPY      .009
```

How do I construct such a formula for my data fx column?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VLOOKUP with multiple criteria](http://superuser.com/questions/685818/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria)

Answer (score 2):

While a two column criteria lookup is very doable, you would only be picking up the first *fx* value. Since there should be only one set of matching pairs, a [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5) is a very efficient alternative.

```
=SUMIFS(C:C, A:A, F3, B:B, E3)
```

[image: EUR USD conversion]

`C:C` » column from which the result should be taken (if the following two criterias meet)
`A:A` » column to search in for your first criteria
`F3`  » cell which holds your first criteria
`B:B` » column to search in for your second criteria
`E3`  » cell which holds your second criteria

<sup>- Can be expanded up to 127 criterias

- If you drag down this formula `F3` and `E3` should be changed automatically</sup>